# Mysql using max(count/ group by) using join

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, max

I have two tables(titleauthor, authors)
there are names in authors,

and contents of written books in titleauthor(counts)

I would like to get the name of author in authors by using max in counts in titleauthor. I think i used command wrong.. Can anyone correct this?

```
use pubs;

select (a.au_fname," ", a.au_lname) as Author_Name
from authors a
join titleauthor ta
on a.au_id = ta.au_id
where max(count(*)) group by ta.au_id;   // or where max(count(*) group by ta.au_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only expect a single author to have the most titles then you can try the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.au_fname, ' ', a.au_lname) AS Author_Name
FROM authors a
INNER JOIN titleauthor ta
    ON a.au_id = ta.au_id
GROUP BY a.au_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If there could be a tie between authors for the most titles, then you could specify a second column which could be used to break the tie.  This would work well if you only want to report a single author.  If you really want to report all authors should there be a tie, then we can use a subquery for that.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need the fields in the `select` to appear also in the `group by`
And then you can `order by` the count descending and `limit` to 1

```
select concat(a.au_fname," ", a.au_lname) as Author_Name
from authors a
    join titleauthor ta
    on a.au_id = ta.au_id
group by a.au_fname, a.au_lname
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: This has a potential problem in the case that two different authors happen to have the same first and last name.  Not likely to occur, but it could happen.

Comment: Thanks! I thought i need to use max in this one :P